# How do I add plugins to my Bukkit SMP server?

Tags: mods, minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit

I was wondering how to add plugins to my Minecraft server. I am using Bukkit, and the things I would like to be able to do is spawn stuff, teleport to other players, set home locations, have an in-game currency/shop and be able to teleport to homes.

Comment: I think you mean, Plugins.

Answer (score 18):

I would suggest you to download and configure the following bukkit plugins:

- [Permissions](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/admn-dev-permissions-v2-5-2-phoenix-now-with-more-antibuild-493.5974/). Allows you to set up groups and commands for other users.
- [Essentials](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/gen-essentials-v2-0-collection-of-essential-plugins-in-one-package-multiple.1262/). Gives you /item, /spawn, /tp, /home, /warp, /time and much more.
- [iConomy](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/econ-iconomy-4-3-2-lind-400-plugin-authors-please-update.40/). Sets up an currency system. Also gives you the possibility to withdraw and insert "Eura" (as the currency is called) into a users account.

There is also a [full list of server mods/plugins](http://dev.bukkit.org/server-mods/).

With a quick search on the [Bukkit forums](http://forums.bukkit.org/), I found the plugin [LocalShop](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/econ-localshops-1-5b-440-player-shops-for-iconomy.6744/), that seems like what you asked for about shops.

As for the "teleport to others homes" part, I'm still looking for something myself. But I guess the best thing is to ask the Essentials creator to implement this.

I also advice you to install [HeroChat](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/chat-herochat-v4-1-4-complete-chat-addon-493.2497/), as it's a pretty good chat plugin, and [BigBrother](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/sec-bigbrother-1-6-3-a-complete-griefer-logging-rollback-package-440.166/) as it's a very good system to help fix griefing.

Plugins are usually installed by placing them in the /plugins folder, but some plugins also have custom installation steps, and these steps are usually detailed in the forum post.

Comment: Nice answer! I've edited in the links for you, as it wouldn't let you do it yourself

Comment: I should also advise to use BigBrother to help fix griefers: [BigBrother @ Bukkit Forums](http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/sec-bigbrother-1-6-3-a-complete-griefer-logging-rollback-package-440.166/)

Comment: thank every one for there feed back!! and im not really worried about griefing cuz it a family

Answer (score 0):

He is asking for a mod not a plugin.

First download `minecraft_server.jar` from [minecraft.net](http://minecraft.net) and extract all the things in the file in to `minecraft_server.jar`. Download a mod and put all the things inside it into `minecraft_server.jar`. That's what I heard.

Comment: I voted your answer up. The fact that this got -2 is pitiful.

Comment: From context everyone understood that the asker meant "bukkit plugins", but this answer doesn't help with that. The word they use really isn't important when most people treat the words "plugin", "mod", and "addon" as interchangeable, *especially* when what they mean is obvious despite using the "wrong" word.

Answer (score 0):

Well it sounds like you have already got the server up from the title.
Go to this http://plugins.bukkit.org/ to get plugins.If you're using Google chrome its going to say it might be unsafe or similar click OK or continue.Then drag the plugin into the plugin folder C:\Users\YourUser\Desktop\plugin\plugins that's the directory.

A plugin for money I recommend BOSEconomy 
http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/boseconomy/

A plugin for homes i reccomend http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/uhome/
It allows your players to have multiple homes and has a easy command /sethome

A plugin for shops get chestshop http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/chestshop/