# How can I play Minecolony in SMP?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

[Minecolony](http://www.minecraftforum.net/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=125803) is a nice SSP mod that adds some NPCs like a farmer and a miner. How can I make that work on SMP as well? I can put the ingredients for the items together but not craft them, and using `give` returns that the items don't exist. I tried adding all files from the mod into the `minecraft_server.jar` without success, so

> How can Minecolony be played on SMP? Or are there at least some other nice NPC SMP mods?

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/17698/how-do-i-add-mods-to-my-minecraft-smp-server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mod is not currently compatible with SMP.

EDIT:

I did some digging through the topic, and through the guy's website.  He will start working on SMP after he finishes the single player version

Comment: That's why I ask "_How_ can Minecolony played on SMP"

Comment: "The mod is not currently compatible with SMP." means "it CAN'T be played on SMP".

Comment: Tyr: do you maybe have link?

Comment: It's the big one on his link.  With red letters in front of it.
http://sites.google.com/site/minecolony/home

Answer (score 3):

1) Learn how to program java

2) Learn how to decompile .class files

3) spend some time figuring out what the .class files are doing

4) write code that makes minecolony work with smp

or wait for the author to do it.