# How do I add Mods to a Minecraft SMP Server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

I am currently using the Bukkit Server and a couple mods/plugins such as LocalShops, Craftbook, Iconomy, and so on.

However, far more interesting mods (in my opinion) are out there, and I have NO CLUE how to implement them.

For example...
[The Pistons Mod](http://www.minecraftforum.net/viewtopic.php?f=1032&t=247686&p=3744497&sid=df550523b04e5fd8867e87f82d047c87)
and 
[The Planes Mod](http://www.minecraftforum.net/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=198188)

Everyone seems to have explanations for how to install these mods in SSP or Singleplayer, and I have been completely unsuccessful in attempting to figure it out myself.

I understand Planes Mod currently does not support Bukkit.  And I am willing to kill the Bukkit server and start a different one so long as similar mods to Localshops and Craftbook can be found for said new server.

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/17698/how-do-i-add-mods-to-my-minecraft-smp-server ?

Comment: I think he's asking if he can add single player mods to a Bukkit server. I believe you can't, but I'm not sure.

Comment: related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/17712/how-to-play-minecolony-in-smp

Answer (score 3):

For a mod to work in multiplayer, the author needs to create a SMP version. The most common way is through bukkit.

However if a mod adds new items, like the two examples you have given, playing SMP with it will require both a server mod and client mod to work together. This usually means the same developer or team needs to make both. If they don't provide both yet add new items, the mod is likely single player only.

For combining several of these mods, they all need to use compatible methods of adding themselves. If one is a bukkit mod while the other is its own mod that conflicts with bukkit you're usually out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

I've gotten it to work on a Bukkit server partially. FalseBook, MobRider and Essentials will NOT accept the mod, however. They will continuously send out errors on: BLOCK_PLACE, BLOCK_REMOVE, PLAYER_INTERACT and PLAYER_ANIMATION. Apart from that, new items ARE craftable, placeable (although this will give the before mentioned errors), and useable, as are the planes.

In this link, you will find a page where you can download an appropriate mod loader for SMP (works, I have personally tested it), a different version of Flan's Planes designed for Bukkit and other mods. Link: http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/382599-173-modloadermp-for-craftbukkit-and-canary/

If anyone knows a way to fix/patch the errors mentioned above (more details if requested) Planes mod would work succesfully and I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

If the mod is using Minecraft Forge(Downloadable here), or ModLoader(able to be used with Forge), yes it is usable on multiplayer since Minecraft 1.3. Forge can be installed using the following instructions:

### Step 1

Download Forge from the link above. Use (Installer).

[image]

### Step 2

Fill in the folder and click "OK"

[image]

### Step 3

The installer will install some files and create a server. Once it is done you will see this screen. Hit "OK" to exit the installer.

[image]

### Step 4

Go to the folder with the server, create a mods folder, and put the mods inside.

### Step 5

Double-click on "forge-x.x.x-xx.xx.x.xxxx-universal.jar" where x is a number to start the server.

### Step 6

Connect to "localhost" with the mods on your client and you should be in!

Answer (score 0):

For others who come here: Unless you're really serious in figuring out how to do this yourself, I recommend just using a premade mod package for both your client and your server. Two examples which provides both:

- **[TechnicPack](http://www.technicpack.net)**, launcher for client, server downloads through website)
- **[ATLauncher](http://www.atlauncher.com)**, launcher for client, server downloads through launcher

Combined provide enough packages that are extensive enough that at least I have enough fun for a while.